# tabpage icon change on text change

Tags: vb.net

I have a tab_control on a form and couple of tab_pages. Each tab_page has some controls like text_box, check_box etc. I have assigned an image list to tab_control and have assigned image_key property with respective image. 
Now what I want to achieve is, when the text changes in any of the tab_page the image of respective tab_page should also change.

Please be informed that I am not talking about background image, I am talking about icons of tab_pages.

Thanks

Comment: TabControl.SelectedTab.ImageIndex = ...

Comment: can you please elaborate on this

Comment: In your TextBox TextChanged event, call that.

Comment: Hey Lars, It did worked, i called this event on a button_click event and it did changed the icon. Gratitude